# Audio input delay in VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, virtualbox, pulseaudio, 20.04, microphone

I have a very strange problem regarding audio input passthrough in a Ubuntu 20.04 VM. In general, I am able to passthrough the audio input of my headset to my VM. That works. However, after some time a delay is building up. The longer the VM is running, the longer it takes for the VM to process my headset input.

Freshly booted, there is almost no delay. After 20 minutes of runtime, I have a 15 second delay between me speaking and the VM recognizing audio input. I verified that my host system does recognize the audio input instantly. Looking at the vu meters in pavucontrol it seems like that my host system also passes the audio on to the VM instantly. However, in my VM the vu meters react with the very noticeable delay. The situation is reproduceable by rebooting the VM.

Audio output passed from the VM to my host system headphones works with almost no delay. I can tweak that with pavucontrol and it doesn't bother me.

My host system is also a Ubuntu 20.04 and I am using VirtualBox 6.1.6. My audio settings in the VBoxManager are pulseaudio as host driver and ICH AC97 as Controller. Changing the host driver results in no audio devices recognized within the VM. And changing the Controller results in my headset not being recognized as audio input.

I have no idea why that delay is buiding up over time.

**EDIT:**
The problem still persists and is reproducible on multiple VMs. Therefore I expect it to be a problem with either my host system and or my Virtual Box settings. I do have a work around, but no general solution. My headset uses an external DAC, that is attached via USB to my host machine. I can passthrough that USB device and use my headset directly within the VM. In this constellation there is no input delay.

Regards

Comment: Am I really the only one having this problem and nobody has a clue?

Comment: Sorry, found your post while looking up other sound issues with 20.04 and VBox, but I've never seen/heard this sound delay problem you describe.

Comment: I also am having the same issues. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @AndrewGreer, unfortunately not. But see my edit for a possible work around.

Comment: since weeks i got only audo out from kubuntu client to kubuntu host. now i got audio in to the app audacity if i use ALSA sydefault Phon 0 thert. but i got no audio in by using skype. host: PulseAudio, ICH AC 97

Comment: I also have this problem. Guest: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Host: Fedora 32. Virtualbox version: 6.1.18

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem but my host and guest are both Arch. I have tried adjusting various pulseaudio settings on host and guest, and switching to pipewire-pulse (which was even worse). I have also been working around it by passing my USB mic through.

Another work around is to enable pulseaudio to listen on a tcp port on the host and then set PULSE_SERVER to the host IP in /etc/environment in the guest (and restart the guest). This will make the guest pass sound through to the pulseaudio server on the host.

I have to use Anyconnect VPN in the guest for work, so unfortunately I cannot connect to the host IP from the guest when VPN is active, but that might be an easier solution for you.